# Why creating database dynamically does not work?

Tags: python, string, sqlite, formatting

My function:

```py
def create_dbtest():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print ("Opened database successfully")
    temp = "ID integer primary key autoincrement not null, FECHA datetime default current_timestamp"

    table = '""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE' + ' (' + temp + '); """' #<<< WHY IT DOES NOT WORK?
    ##    table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE (ID integer primary key autoincrement not null, FECHA datetime default current_timestamp); """

    print (table)
    cursor.execute(table)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print ("Closed database successfully")
```

Why the second `temp` variable (the commented) line builds the database file successfully but the first one doesn't? Error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near """" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE (ID integer primary key autoincrement not null, FECHA datetime default current_timestamp); """": syntax error

Comment: ‘”"" Will add 3 double quote at the beginning and also end of the command. While in 2nd case, the 3 double quotes are not included in the final string by python.